# Curl "Please refresh and try again. " error, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Project, where i want to create a cronjob or a event what will call a defined route. My old project is working with this script but this one don't want to work.

My bash:

```
#! /bin/sh
curl -s localhost/ -d "email=email&password=password" -c cookiefile  &&
curl -s "localhost/route/0" -b cookiefile
```

I got this error:

```
The page has expired due to inactivity.
 Please refresh and try again.
```

Comment: Your cookie has expired

Comment: And how can i make a valid cookie or a functional script to don't get this error ?